# recommended file location for samba share

Tags: debian, samba, filesystems

I'm setting up a samba share on our office server (debian sqeeze). Is there a recommended location where to put the share on the file system in debian?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either `/home` for home directories or `/srv` for other files, as per the [FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#SRVDATAFORSERVICESPROVIDEDBYSYSTEM).

Or put it where you can find it and where it's logical for you. I usually mount data partitions under `/data`.

Comment: +1, especially for the FHS

Answer (score 1):

I've commonly seen `/shared` or `/var/shared/` (or the like) used